# Twitter Bootstrap 3 form-inline text input width depends on label width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've noticed strange behavior of the Twitter Bootstrap 3: size of the input box depends on the size of its label when they are grouped with form-group:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a3vAP/4/

Is this feature or bug? What would be the fix? I need input boxes of the same size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The longer label is causing the input to be longer since they're both contained in the same `form-group` which uses `display:inline-block` so it's automatically sizing to the width of the `label`.

According the Bootstrap docs..

> "Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap.
>   To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form
>   controls used within."

So, you'd need to add some simple CSS to control the width..

```
.form-inline .form-group input {
    width:140px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/87747

Comment: One thing I did note - this CSS did not work correctly for me as I too was using a `form-inline` class. Inspecting the Bootstrap docs 1st there was the following: "This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide". The resulting CSS inspection also yielded the following in the browser: `@media (min-width: 768px)` Therefore my overriding style wouldn't take effect until the viewport was < 768, and then my input changed to the size I wanted using the CSS from this answer. :S You'll have to deal with this media query if using `form-inline`